# In Azure DevOps, developers are unable to access sprint boards and other boards due to permissions issue

Tags: azure-devops, user-permissions

Developers are receiving this message when trying to access the sprint board and other boards.

[image: Access Denied: Carlos Ponce De Leon needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: View instance-level information]

This permission appears to be set for the project team through inheritance from "Project Collection Valid Users".  Project Admin users can access the boards.

[image: View instance-level information is set to: Allow (inherited)]

Comment: Hi Stan, is there any update for this issue? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917788/10910450), `Explicit deny overrides explicit allows.`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click the **Members** tab and choose the specific user, check if the `View-instance-level` information is `Allow` for the user.

[image]

There're two possible causes of the issue:

1.Once we grant several permissions(Allow) to one team, the members of that team can access the `Allowed` permissions automatically. But if we disable/deny the permission of **one specific user**, then the user can't access the permission though his team can.

2.Also, if one user is in both teams A and B. If TeamA has `Allow` permission to `View instance-level information` while TeamB has `Deny` status to `View instance-level information`. Then the users in TeamA but not TeamB can access the Allowed permissions while the users in both TeamA and TeamB is denied to access the Allowed permission.